# Javascript rendering conflict or bug

Tags: css, z-index

This is the second question i have had to ask regarding the building of my site and it involves Javascript which is well over my head.

The problem:

When the user highlights over the menu (sprybar) and causes the drop down to appear on the About Us section, then clicks an image in the gallery the spry bar somehow overlays itself over the image the user has clicked on - very annoying!

here is a link to the site http://sweetvision.co.uk/dynamicpages/gallery.html.

Also I'm a complete amateur at this website building stuff so don't laugh too hard so any other pointers would be great also!

if code is required i will post it up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `z-index` for your menu is way too high (at least higher than the lightbox's).

**sweetvision.css:633**

```
ul.MenuBarActive {
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Try removing this rule altogether.

Comment: Ha as simple as that! Thanks it worked a treat. I honestly thought it was a Javascript conflict. I should really have worked that on out!